# How to run a PowerShell command silently?

Tags: powershell

I want to execute a **PowerShell** command silently 
with no blue screen.

How can I do this from the **PowerShell** command?

I tried this. . .

```
PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden
```

but it didn't work—the command was executed but with the blue screen still.

Comment: I actually dont want to run powershell script but command

Comment: if you see above I tride to run the same command you gve it to me

Answer (score 8):

### Run a PowerShell Command Silently from a Prompt

As stated. . .

> ["*You can use PowerShell.exe to start a PowerShell session from the
>   command line of another tool, such as Cmd.exe, or use it at the
>   PowerShell command line to start a new session. Use the parameters to
>   customize the session.*"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6)
>
> ---
>
> **-WindowStyle**
>
> Sets the window style for the session. Valid values are Normal,
>   Minimized, Maximized and Hidden.
>
> **-Command**
>
> Executes the specified commands (and any parameters) as though they
>   were typed at the PowerShell command prompt, and then exits, unless
>   the NoExit parameter is specified. Essentially, any text after
>   `-Command` is sent as a single command line to PowerShell

---

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> powershell -windowstyle hidden -command <PowerShell Command String>
> ```

---

### Verifiable Examples

> **1. Command Prompt (cmd)**
>
> ```
> powershell -windowstyle hidden -command get-childitem -path c:\ ^| out-file "C:\Folder\Log\log.txt"
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> > **Note:** *With cmd the [`|`] pipe symbol needs escaped with the [`^`] caret symbol  so "`^|`".*

---

> **2. PowerShell Prompt**
>
> ```
> powershell -windowstyle hidden -command get-childitem -path c:\ | out-file "C:\Folder\Log\log.txt"
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> > **Note:** *After running, open **log.txt** to verify its content since `out-file` directs it the output.*

---

### Further Resources

- [PowerShell.exe Command-Line Help](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6)

Comment: If you get an error stating something along the lines of  "***Powershell' is not recognized~***" you can firstly and simply run `CD /D "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0"` and then run the PowerShell commands with applicable parameters and such directly afterwards until you get your environmental variables straightened out otherwise.

Comment: Is it possible to write something in the PowerShell script so it will hide the windows when it starts?

Comment: I thought the #2 example did that. I'd have to dig and test to confirm but I know I've done this before with logon scripts with a group policy so I know it's possible. Test a variation of the #2 example logic and see what you get. If it does not work as you need it, open a question with what you are trying and someone will help you get it figured out.

Comment: Thanks but, for information, `powershell -windowstyle hidden` on the top of my PowerShell script did not work (I launch it by clicking on its "as admin" shortcut).

Comment: I see, see if you change it up a bit and allow the PowerShell execution to do the "run as admin" by using the **PowerShell (Solution 1)** as written about here https://superuser.com/questions/1619630/run-powershell-script-as-a-different-user-and-elevated/1619700#1619700 and see if executing the PS this way with elevated admin and not use the shortcut to do that. Does this solution the problem you mention here by chance? @JinSnow The `Start-Process` line in particular.

Comment: Even though windowstyle works somewhat, the powershell window is still shown for a split second.

Comment: Thanks @BluE I'll see if I notice this when I test with it. I know you can run as `SYSTEM` via task scheduler to keep it hidden and just execute PS, or with a login script with GP option to not show running login scripts (or something like that) but it's been a while since I've messed with it.

Comment: Well, I had it running from task scheduler, so that might have caused it too. The key was to let it run independently of logon. Now I don't notice the task anymore. Depending on the use case, this setting could cause other problems, though.

Comment: @BluE True, it's all about under what security context, I totally agree! I like machine level startup scripts for machine level stuff as those run as `SYSTEM` by default and just work. Keep it chugging like a train.... choo, choo!!! All aboard!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where I picked these lines up at but some nice functions to show and hide the console.

#### Show/Hide Powershell Window

```
Function Show-Console {
$consolePtr = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow()
[Console.Window]::ShowWindow($consolePtr, 5)
}

Function Hide-Console {
$consolePtr = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow()
[Console.Window]::ShowWindow($consolePtr, 0)
}
```

I use it for my gui apps when I want to hide the ps in background:

#### Map: Show/Hide Powershell Windows Checkbox

```
$cb_PSCheckbox.Add_Checked({Show-Console})
$cb_PSCheckbox.Add_UnChecked({Hide-Console})
```

Comment: but the language of the code is c# or powershell

Comment: can you give me a method for vb.net

Answer (score 0):

Another option to run PowerShell scripts completely hidden (not even a flash) is to use this little [**RunHidden**](https://lesferch.github.io/RunHidden/) executable.