# How to hide PsExec cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, psexec

I'm starting the PsExec using Powershell:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "psexec.exe" -ArgumentList "-u user -p pass -accepteula -i -h cmd /c `"powershell.exe -NonInteractive -File myscript.ps1`""
```

But the PsExec CMD is visible until the powershell script `myscript.ps1` is finished.

So how can I hide PsExec CMD ?

Comment: Related questions : https://superuser.com/questions/1331143/how-to-run-a-powershell-command-silently  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window

Answer (score 1):

I asked the wrong question.

Since I'm starting the `PsExec` using `Start-Process` then I can control it very easily with `-windowstyle hidden` as explained on the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window which was posted by @Christoper Hostage