How to play an audio file without any window and only if it's not already being played?

I log errors.
Some errors in my log viewer I run an executable.
That executable plays a sound.
I know to look at my log.

This works great until I'm working on something that suddenly wants to trigger this say, a three thousand times in 500ms. When that happens… Let's just say Windows isn't designed to play 3000 instances of the same audio file at the same time.
I've been using Sounder to play the sounds without showing any windows. It works great, provided you don't try to open it 3,000 times in the span of 500ms.
So recently my work has lead me directly in to encountering stupid numbers of errors very quickly. So I remembered that I have a batch program that loads all of my programs (but skips any that are already open). So I adapted that to load sounder:
C:

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set EXE=sounder.exe
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF %%x == %EXE% goto FOUND
cd "C:\example"
start sounder.exe "C:\example\potato_timer_01.wav"
goto FIN
:FOUND
echo Sounder is already running.
:FIN

The problem here is that running the batch files now opens a window which is what I don't want.
Okay fine...so I did more research and someone on another thread said that running a VBS script can hide the window:
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "sounder_potato_timer_01.bat", 0, True

This works great...if I open it manually. However my log program fails to open it (I have no idea why, I don't hear anything and I don't get any error messages or see any windows open). So I'm going out on a limb on the notion that the log viewer won't accept just any command line executable types.
Yes, I've tried researching other programs such as VLC though they apparently don't support windowless execution. I'm out of options here and would be grateful for any constructive suggestions to accomplishing my goal. So in short:
How do I run a bat or exe file without any window being displayed and only have it play the file if no other instances are running?
My log viewing program is Hoo Wintail (it has a free trial). I am happy to entertain updating my question to note which other executable types do and do not work. I am also happy to try other command-line programs other than sounder.exe if someone has a helpful recommendation.
Please remember, my goal is to be able to encounter swarms of errors without is debilitating my computer. That way I can determine what is broken, fix it and not have other people be forced to encounter swarms of errors.

Try PowerShell? No idea why batch is the first thought. https://superuser.com/questions/1331143/how-to-run-a-powershell-command-silently

@Destroy666 It looks like half of anyone using PowerShell says -WindowStyle Hidden flat out does not work. Example: powershell Start-Process -FilePath “C:\example\sounder_back.vbs” -WindowStyle Hidden still shows a window from the run command.

take a look at converting you bat into an exe and then into a windows service. This will keep everything hidden and working. May need to be a bit more robust, but then you can enable the service to come at windows login and most of your issues may be solved.

@John it does work, it shows a window for a second and then hides it. If you don't want even that then try e.g., pythonw.

@Destroy666 Showing a window is the opposite of working and is as off-topic as it gets on this thread.
